# Render react component after redirecting (Next.js, serversiderendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

i'm new to next.js, and stucked in one problem
i have some static links which are redirecting to search.tsx under pages folder

current behavior :
now, if i click on any links , first it will wait for API response and then render search page

expected : -
it should render first and then wait for API response

search.tsx

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (props: any) => {
    const apiResponse = await api.getProperties()
    return {
       props: {
       ...apiResponse,
   },
  }
}
const Search = (props: any) => {
  </searchResult>
}
export default Search
```

Comment: You have to move your API call in useEffect() with [] dependency so it will run only after component load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getServerSideProps` runs whenever the page exporting this `async` function is **requested**, `getServerSideProps` is used for `SSR`, if you want to render the page and then `fetch` data, then you will have to do it in `client` side, you can use `useEffect` which can be used to **fetch** data because it only runs on the `client` side.

```
useEffect(()=>{
 async function fetchData(){
    // getch data fro API and set state

 },
fetchData()
},[])
```

refer [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) for more about `getServerSideProps`

Comment: You forgot to call the fetchData();

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer
and I understood what you are trying to say

the thing I wanted to know is if we remove the getServerSideProps() method, and use useEffect(), what are real-time disadvantages we will see
, I have read somewhere that getServerSideProps() is beneficial for SEO
and my page is really user interactive that means it will need to make API requests on every user ACTION under it.
so, can you tell me what are disadvantages,? it will be great help